# How to create a custom Array Object based on different recordId?

Tags: soql

I am a bit new to salesforce, so kindly help.

I have different recordsIDS like from contacts, opportunities,leads and other sections, I need to use SQL Query and return the Name and Email.

My code follows as this, kindly help how to create a custom list and return based on ID.

I am getting errors such as unexpected Name and email,so how to create a custom SOQL query or which can work here.

```
@AuraEnabled
  public static List <Contact> getAccountDetails(String recordId){
    
 //  List<Contact> results = [SELECT Name, Email 
   //FROM Contact 
          

       If (recordId.startsWith('003')){
          return [SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE id = :recordId];
    }
    
              
    If (recordId.startsWith('00Q')){
      return [SELECT Name, Email FROM Lead WHERE id = :recordId];
    }
       
    
      If (recordID.startsWith('006')){
         return [SELECT 'Name', 'Email' FROM 'OpportunityContactRole' WHERE 'OpportunityId'= :recordId];
    }
    
   If (recordID.startsWith('0Q0'){
      return [SELECT Name, Email FROM Quote WHERE id = :recordId];
    }
         
    If (recordID.startsWith('001')){
           return [SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE id = :recordId];
     }
       
    If (recordID.startsWith('003'))
         return [SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE id = :recordId];
    }
}
```

Adding controller code as well for reference

```
  getCurrentPageDetails : function(component, event, helper) {
     
     var action  = component.get("c.getAccountDetails");
     console.log(action,"action")
     action.setParams({
        'recordId' : component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        debugger
        var status = response.getState();
        if(status === "SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.name",response.getReturnValue()[0].Name )
            component.set("v.email",response.getReturnValue()[0].Email)
            
        }
    });
    
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
   
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For the related objects, you'll want to use the Contact relationship, etc. For example:

```
return [SELECT Contact.Name, Contact.Email FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId = :recordId];
```

You'll want to check the [data model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/data_model.htm) and/or the [Schema Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_modeling/schema_builder) to figure out the relationships. Also, fields are never `'Quoted'` in SOQL.

Comment: Thanks, But getting this error Illegal conversion from List<OpportunityContactRole> to List<Contact>

Comment: @nms You'll want to change the method to `public static List<sObject>`.